# How to insert key value object into lua table inside redis

Tags: arrays, lua, redis, insert, lua-table

```
local users = {}
table.insert(users, {['uid']= 'xxx'})
```

How to insert object into table in Lua script. When I try to insert, Lua returns empty array, with empty array inside "[[]]".

```
table.insert(users, 'xxx')
```

When I insert string, it is properly returned. "['xxx']"

I'm running Lua inside redis. In node.

JavaScript example would be:

```
const arr = []
arr.push({uid: 'xxx'})
```

Comment: Your original code works for me... how did you check that "Lua returns empty array"? I suspect that you tried returning users table to your (node?) client...

Answer (score 4):

try this method to get element : users[1].uid  or  users[1].['uid']

```
local users = {}
table.insert(users, { ['uid'] = 'xxx'})
table.insert(users, { uid = 'yyy'})

print(users[1].uid)
print(users[2].uid)
```

output:

```
xxx
yyy
```

Comment: Please make it a more elaborate answer.